# Get the remaining value from list of possible values (inline if possible)

Tags: python

I have 3 integers in a list (0,1,2) and ask the user to set these values to 3 different objects. I want the third item to be autoassigned as simply as possible. I'd like to reference these objects as `stacks[stack_something]`:

```py
# list of stack - one source, one target, one helper
stacks = (
        Stack(),
        Stack(),
        Stack()
    )
# 3 variables that point to indexes in 'stacks'
stack_s = userSet() # user chooses which is the source (input)
stack_t = userSet() # user chooses which is the target (output)
stack_h = [0,1,2].remove(stack_in).remove(stack_to).pop() # something like this
```

Let's say user chooses 1, then 3. So `stack_h` should automatically get `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
stack_h = (set([0,1,2])-{stack_s, stack_t}).pop()
```

Here the outer parenthesis is just used as enclosers, on which `.pop()` operates. The curly braces signify [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). And `set()` call converts the `list` to a `set`. Just like `[]` is used for `list`, `()` is used for `tuple`, `{}` is used for `set` and `dictionary`. 
A difference between `set` and `dictionary` is:

```
# set
s = {1,2,3}
# dictionary
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

So dictionary are collection of values with unique keys. 
`sets` are collection of unordered unique elements, very handy for membership checking, and are normally faster than list methods in these cases. I would suggest you to look up `sets`.

Comment: Thank you. Obviously I can't wrap my head around these parentheses in python.

Comment: I will add some explanation.

Comment: Ok, after reading the explanation, I can just use `stack_h = ({0,1,2}-{stack_s, stack_t}).pop()`

Comment: Correct. I thought `[0,1,2]` is going to be a variable at some point, that's why I used `set()` call, but if you type it manually, then your method will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

This could also work for you:

```
stacks = [0, 1, 2]
stack_s = int(input('stack_s'))
stack_t = int(input('stack_t'))
stack_h = [x for x in stacks if x not in [stack_s, stack_t]][0]
print(stack_h)
```